# How to count total customers using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is the example of the JSON. I want to count the total customers by unique "email_address" and  filter by "transactions_status" equal to "S".

Expected output:

```
    {
_id: null, 
count: total amount of customers with an unique email address and filtered by status  equal S 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Manfred, DO NOT post images of code, Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

You can try this aggregations pipeline:

1. Filter by "transactions_status" equal to "S".
2. Group distinct emails.
3. Project the count field with the emails's size.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "transaction_info.transaction_status": "S"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      emails: {
        $addToSet: "$payer_info.email_address"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      count: {
        $size: "$emails"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to count customers too so i had to use orders collection to do so since the order's collection have customer field which I can use to get total customers here is my aggregation

```
    [
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "$shop",
          {
            $toObjectId:
              "653a5a695c5ace2932dd3765",
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          orderStatus: {
            $ne: "deleted",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      uniqueCustomers: {
        $addToSet: "$customer",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "customers count",
      customers: {
        $size: "$uniqueCustomers",
      },
    },
  },
]
```